# Angular2 how to mock backend for development

Tags: angular, mocking, xmlhttprequest, backend

I am writing an application in angular2 and I want to mock backend, which is just not ready at this point.

This is my service:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Headers, Response, RequestOptions } from '@angular/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';

import { Item } from './item';

@Injectable()
export class ItemService {

    private itemUrl = 'api/item';  // URL to web api

    constructor(private http: Http) { }

    getItems(): Observable<Item[]> {
        return this.http
            .get(this.itemUrl)
            .map(this.extractData)
            .catch(this.handleError);
    }

    addItem(name: string): Observable<Item> {
        let body = JSON.stringify({ name });
        let headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });
        let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });

        return this.http.post(this.itemUrl, body, options)
            .map(this.extractData)
            .catch(this.handleError);
    }

    private extractData(res: Response) {
        let body = res.json();
        return body.data || {};
    }

    private handleError(error: any) {
        let errMsg = 'error';
        return Observable.throw(errMsg);
    }
}
```

And I would like to intercept every request which is made to "itemUrl" in my TypeScript code and make simple operations on usual list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should probably use the `angular-in-memory-web-api`. See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39942256/2587435) for an example. Also check out [the documentation](https://github.com/angular/in-memory-web-api/blob/master/README.md). In the long run, using this will probably save you more time than trying to use Angular's `MockBackend`. You can use the in-memory-web-api both for unit testing testing *and* development.

Comment: What about the fact that angular-in-memory-web-api is "experimental and not intended for production use"?

Comment: @RuiMarques why would you want to use it for production? It's really only for development and demos.