# Wrapping external script in Angular2 service

Tags: angular, angular2-services

I have an `angular-cli` generated project that I would like to use with a [deployd](http://deployd.com/) backend. Deployd provides a script for accessing it's API's that can be loaded from `http://<deployd-host>/dpd.js`. This creates a global `dpd` object that can access the API from javascript global context (e.g. from Chrome dev tools console).

I would like to wrap this in an Angular2 service so I can inject a mock one for testing etc. The tasks are to load the script from the URL and then gain access to the global `dpd` object. I've looked at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34489916/load-external-js-script-dynamically-in-angular-2) SO post but haven't been able to get the accepted answer to work. If I add the script manually to the `document` object, I can't access the dpd object on `window`.

Also, the URL that the script is loaded from will be different based on environments, e.g. `http://localhost:3000/dpd.js` for local dev, `http://dev.example.com/dpd.js` for staging and `http://www.example.com/dpd.js` for production. So ideally I would be able to configure that in the service as well.

Looking for something like below to work.

```
@Injectable()
export class DpdService {
  constructor() {
    if (getEnvironmentSomeHow() == 'development') {
      loadScriptFrom("http://localhost:3000/dpd.js");
    } else {
      loadScriptFrom("http://dev.example.com/dpd.js");
    }
    dpd = window.dpd;
  }

  public session(): Observable<Session> {
    return Observable.fromPromise(dpd.sessions.get());
  }
}
```

Comment: can you able to share some code

Comment: Possible duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39942118/how-to-inject-different-service-based-on-certain-build-environment-in-angular2/39942256#39942256   Very detailed explanation with code

Comment: And what is the problem that you have with the approach you've shown in the question?

Comment: @estus 1. Don't know how to the environment, 2. Don't have an elegant implementation for `loadScriptFrom`, 3. If loading by adding a script tag to the document, the dpd object is not available on the window when I use it. If I check from console in Chrome, it's available, so that seems like an async issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Application environment totally depends on the choice of the developer. These can be conditionally included TS files that depend on Node environment variable. It can be a single file that defines Angular providers depending on client-side global variable (likely provided with Webpack `DefinePlugin` or `EnvironmentPlugin`, see [`angular2-webpack-starter`](https://github.com/AngularClass/angular2-webpack-starter/blob/master/src/app/environment.ts) for example). In its most simple form it is just client-side global `ENV` variable, all decisions are made in-place - it can even be set in HTML with server-side templating:

```
<script>
   window.ENV = <% SERVER_SIDE_ENV_VARIABLE %>
</script>
```

Due to the fact that the script should be loaded on app initialization, it has to be loaded in `APP_INITIALIZER` multiprovider:

```
...
import {APP_INITIALIZER} from '@angular/core'
import {DOCUMENT} from '@angular/platform-browser'

@Injectable()
export class DpdService {
  dpd: any;

  constructor(@Inject(DOCUMENT) document: Document) {}

  load() {
    const srcBase = window.ENV === 'dev'
      ? 'http://localhost:3000/'
      : 'http://dev.example.com/';

    const script = this.document.createElement('script');
    this.document.body.appendChild(script);

    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      script.onload = resolve;
      script.onerror = reject;
      script.async = true;
      script.src = srcBase + 'dpd.js';
    }).then(() => {
      this.dpd = window.dpd;
    });
  }

  session(): Observable<Session> {
    return Observable.fromPromise(this.dpd.sessions.get());
  }
}

export function dpdAppInitializerFactory(dpdService: DpdService) {
  return () => dpdService.load();
}

...
providers: [
  DpdService,
  {
    provide: APP_INITIALIZER,
    useFactory: dpdAppInitializerFactory,
    deps: [DpdService],
    multi: true
  }
],
```

...

At the point when the app is initialized, the promise from `load` method is fulfilled and `dpd` property is set.

Comment: That works great. A couple of things... `DpdService.load()` should be `dpdService.load()`. Also, after doing this, I get `Error encountered resolving symbol values statically. Function calls are not supported. Consider replacing the function or lambda with a reference to an exported function (position 23:19 in the original .ts file), resolving symbol AppModule`

Comment: As for the environment, this is using `angular-cli` which should manage the environment.

Comment: So the error seems to be an issue with with `aot`... should have nothing to do with your solution.

Comment: To avoid the problems with AoT, it is likely should be `export const dpdAppInitializerFactory = (dpdService: DpdService) => () => dpdService.load()` and  `... useFactory: dpdAppInitializerFactory`.

Comment: That doesn't work... but making it a function does. Could you update your answer...
`export function dpdAppInitializerFactory(dpdService: DpdService) {
  return () => dpdService.load();
}`

Comment: Sure. Glad it worked for you. I don't do AoT myself, but it is usually solved like that, to my knowledge.