# Angular - Provide Service In Production

Tags: angular, service, angular-cli, environment, provider

I would like to provide a Custom ErrorHandler to our angular project when it is build (using angular-cli) in the production environment.

I've tried what's been said [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39942118/how-to-inject-different-service-based-on-certain-build-environment-in-angular2) with no success.

To not leave you without a code sample, this is what I've ended up with:

```
let providers: Provider[] = [
    ...
];

if(environment.production) {
    providers.push({ provide: ErrorHandler, useClass: MyErrorHandler });
}

@NgModule({
    declarations: [
        ...
    ],
    imports: [
        ...
    ],
    bootstrap: [AppComponent],
    providers: providers
})
```

But building (or serving) the app:

```
$ ng build --prod
$ ng serve --prod
```

Does not include this error handler.

How should I proceed to do so ?

Comment: What exactly does "no success" mean with the approach explained in the question you linked to?

Comment: Well, in the link I have to provide a service. Which I don't have in the other case. I only need to provide something in production

Comment: You can provide the default `ErrorHandler` during development and the custom one in production.

Comment: I kept bouncing on ERROR in Error encountered resolving symbol values statically. Function calls are not supported.

Comment: That doesn't seem to be related to providing something only in production or providing a custom error handler. Please post the code that causes the error and the exact error message.

Comment: I found the error, is related to https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/3707. I added my solution to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39942118/how-to-inject-different-service-based-on-certain-build-environment-in-angular2/43854424#43854424