# Remove some service from production build in Angular application

Tags: angular, compilation, angular-cli

We have a service which works as an HTTP interceptor in our development environment. It adds some special debug and authentication headers to ease the development.

However, we don't want this service to appear in production or even to be added to the compiled source code.

How do we completely remove some Angular service from production build?

Are there some kind of compiler directives which we could use?

Comment: You could register a different provider for that service based on environment.   See if this helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39942118/how-to-inject-different-service-based-on-certain-build-environment-in-angular2

Comment: I can configure the provider using factory function and conditional operator with reference to environment variable, but the service will be still referenced in my code. Will it be added to the final build? I'm not sure if compiler (tree shaker) is smart enough to remove unused service this way.

Comment: No it is not, woudl have to use NOOP service implementation of preprocess sources first to remove usages of this service - then tree shaker would do its stuff.