# Need to add @Inject decorator manually in constructor

Tags: angular, typescript

I set up a new Angular 5 project and it seems @Injectable decorator doesn't work. I have to inject manually with @Inject decorator for each parameter of constructors.
I'm using Angular 5.0.5 with TS 2.4.2.
This is my tsconfig.json:

```
{ "compileOnSave": false, "compilerOptions": { "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc", "sourceMap": true, "declaration": false, "moduleResolution": "node", "emitDecoratorMetadata": true, "experimentalDecorators": true, "target": "es5", "typeRoots": [ "node_modules/@types" ], "lib": [ "es2017", "dom" ] } }
```

I lost a lot of time on it and i really don't understand what happens.
Do you have an idea of the problem ?

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that you are maybe trying to inject an interface:

```
constructor(someDependency: SomeInterface) { /* ... */ }
```

The `@inject` decorator will be required.

If you are trying to inject a class:

```
constructor(someDependency: SomeClass) { /* ... */ }
```

The `@injectable` annotation should be enough.

Learn more at [Is it possible to inject interface with angular2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37002522/is-it-possible-to-inject-interface-with-angular2)

If this is not your problem maybe there is something wrong with your project. Maybe you are importing the `"reflect-metadata"` module more than once?

Answer (score 0):

My bad, i just found the problem...
I commented the 'core-js/es7/reflect' import in my polyfill.js.

Thanks to you