# How to replace service implementation in Angular component?

Tags: angular

Structure of classes is:

```
/* Common class */

interface Tree {
}

class TreeBase {
   // Commmon methods for all successors
}
```

Concrete classes:

```
interface TreeLayersActions { do(): void; }
interface TreeMapActions { make(): void; }

TreeLayers extends TreeBase implements TreeMapActions {
}

TreeMap extends TreeBase implements TreeLayersActions{
}
```

So, I try to inject concrete implementation to component:

```
export class TreeComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy, TreeLayersActions, TreeMapActions {
   constructor(private tree: TreeBase) {

   }

         make(): void {
          this.tree.getNodeStyles(node); // Here problem
       }
       do(): void {}
}
```

Problem is that `getNodeStyles` is not presented in `private tree: TreeBase`. Because it is concrete implementation.

I have tried this:

```
constructor(private tree: TreeLayers | TreeMap) {
}
```

Component should work with different service implementations to deligate execution to service.

I have decided to create a service that create a specific tree instance and implements all interfaces from all concrete classes:

```
class TreeService implements TreeLayerActions, TreeMapActions {
  public tree: TreeLayers | TreeSearch;

  constructor(type: string) {
      switch (type) {
      case "layers":
        this.tree = new TreeLayers(null);
        break;
      case "map":
        this.tree = new TreeSearch(null);
    }
 }

 /* Realization interfaces TreeLayerActions and TreeMapActions that deligates calls to service
 changeTileLayer(treeNode: TreeNode): void {
    this.tree.changeTileLayer(treeNode: TreeNode);
 }
 // Other methods
}
```

So, then in component I can inject the service `TreeService` and implement also `TreeLayerActions, TreeMapActions, Tree` interfaces, that deligates calls to service.

I think it is dirty solution, because I pollute the component by all methods from each implementations.

Comment: I have found this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37002587/15099191

Comment: `export class TreeComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy, Tree` like the OnInit Interface

Comment: Okay, but for service what type to specify?

Comment: interfaces are not injectable via DI

Comment: Could you check my question again?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the module you can 'provide' another class to use:

```
providers:[{ provide: Tree, useClass: AnotherTree }]
```

Comment: Sure, but I can not inject interface `Tree`

Comment: And class ` AnotherTree` has own methods that not presented in `Tree`. The Tree contains only common methods for all classes. How to know inside component what is AnotherTree or another class?

Comment: So, I can do this: 
  `constructor(private tree: TreeA | TreeB | TreeC | TreeD) {}` the component should no about concrete realization.

Comment: But from another side if I dont know about concrete service injected I dont know which methos it provides for component despite common methods from Tree

Comment: Create an abstract class Tree and let TreeABCD extend it. Then you have constructor (private tree:Tree) and in your subclass you pass TreeA to super()

Comment: Could you check my question, I have updated

Comment: It is not possibel to create instrance of abstract class

Comment: I have also tried this: `constructor(private tree: TreeLayers | TreeSearch) {}`